# Angular Datatables no me sirve la paginación y el ordenable en el modo "server-side-angular-way"

Tags: angular, datatables, angular5, angular-datatables, angular6

Usando parte de esta guía: [***enlace***](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way)

Como defino la tabla:

```
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  serverSide: true,
  filter: false,
  processing: true,
  autoWidth: true,
  searchable: false,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    that.http
      .post(
        this.url+'categorias/listar',
        {
          "nombre": this.categorias.nombre,
          "status": this.categorias.status,
        }
      ).subscribe(
        resp => {
          console.log(resp.data);
          callback({
            recordsTotal: resp.data.length,
            recordsFiltered: resp.data.length,
            data: resp.data
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log('fallo la conexion al servidor');
        }
      );
  },
  columns: [
    {
      title: 'N°',
      data: 0, 
      searchable: false, 
      orderable: false, 
      render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
        return meta.row+1;
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Nombre',
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return row.nombre;
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Estado',
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        let boton = (row.status) ? 'Activo' : 'Inactivo';
        return boton;
      }
    },
  ],
  order: [[1, 'asc']],
  rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
    const self = this;
    $('td', row).unbind('click');
    $('td', row).bind('click', () => {
      self.dataTableClick(data, row);
    });
    return row;
  },
  initComplete: function (settings, json) {
  },
  fnDrawCallback: function() {

  },
  responsive: true,
  select: {
      style: 'single'
  }
};
```

En mi html simplemente coloco:

```html
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" 
  id="tabla" class="table table-hover table-fixed"></table>
```

Esto me da como resultante lo siguiente:
[image: error]

Cabe destacar que la cant de resultados por pagina deberían ser 10 y todos los resultados los arroja en cada pagina. ¿Alguna idea de como solucionar esto?

***Actualización 1:***

El **backend** es en **slim2**:

```
$app->post("/categorias/listar", function() use($app, $db){
    $method = $app->request()->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($method, true);
    echo json_encode($data);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categorias AS c ";
    if(
        (($data['nombre'] != '')&&($data['nombre'] != null))||
        (($data['status'] != '')&&($data['status'] != null))
    ){
        $sql .= " WHERE ";
        if(($data['nombre'] != '')&&($data['nombre'] != null)){
            $sql .= " nombre LIKE '%".$data['nombre']."%'";
            $sql .= " AND";
        }
        if(($data['status'] != '')&&($data['status'] != null)){
            $sql .= " status='".$data['status']."'";
            $sql .= " AND";
        }
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, -3);
    }
    $sql .= " ORDER BY nombre";
    try {
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $tables = [];
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $tables[] = $row;
        }
        $result = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'code' => 200,
            'data' => $tables,
            'sql' => $sql,
        );
        echo json_encode($result);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: A simple vista no le estas pasando a tu `backend` la configuración de paginado, ni la de orden (esa info esta en `dataTablesParameters`),  por lo que obviamente siempre estas devolviendo el total de registros en el orden por defecto.

Comment: @Marcos no se como configurar esa parte.

Comment: Depende mucho de como lo quieras resolver. Según lo veo, tienes 2 opciones: que lo haga el `backend` (la cual yo te recomendaría) o el `frontend` (es decir, recibir TODO, ordenar y paginar el resultado usando la configuración existente en `dataTablesParameters`

Comment: También me gustaría por **backend**

Comment: Entonces es necesario que edites tu pregunta y agregues en que tecnología esta programado tu `backend` y las partes del código relevantes a la pregunta.

Comment: Eso compete a la BD. Es necesario que agregues una sentencia `WHERE` similar a esto: `WHERE   RowNum >= 1
    AND RowNum < 20 `. El número 1 y 20 tienes que pasarlos a tu controller desde frontend. Así, con angular cada vez que das siguiente sumas 10 y pasas  `WHERE   RowNum >= 11
    AND RowNum < 30 ` a la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problemas

- No estas usando ni enviando la información que `DataTable` pasa a la función `ajax` (eg: `dataTablesParameters`).
- En tu `backend` esta faltando toda la lógica para leer los datos de orden y paginado.

#### Solución

En `javascript` es necesario que envíes `dataTablesParameters`, el cual tiene posee información de orden y paginado (ver [Sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters)) similar a la siguiente:

```
{
  "draw": 2, // Indicador de versión
  "columns": [ // Columnas de la tabla
    {"data": 0, "name": "N°", "searchable": false, "orderable": false, "search": {"value": "", "regex": false}}, 
    {"name": "Nombre", "searchable": false, "orderable": true, "search": {"value": "", "regex": false}}, 
    {"name": "Estado", "searchable": false, "orderable": true, "search": {"value": "", "regex": false}}
  ],
  "order": [{ // Orden de las columnas
    "column": 1,
    "dir": "asc"
  }],
  "start": 0, // Indicador de pagina
  "length": 10 // Indicador de cantidad por pagina
}
```

Para enviarlo, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
...
ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {

  // Agregamos los filtros que actualmente estas enviando
  dataTablesParameters.nombre = this.categorias.nombre;
  dataTablesParameters.status = this.categorias.status;

  that.http
    .post(
      this.url + 'categorias/listar',
      dataTablesParameters // AQUI enviamos los datos
    ).subscribe(
      ....
    );
},
```

---

En `PHP` debes leer dicha información y armar la consulta `SQL` acorde a la misma.
(te recomiendo leer este artículo [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/16597))

Así por ejemplo:

```
$app->post("/categorias/listar", function() use($app, $db){
    $method = $app->request()->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($method, true);
    //echo json_encode($data);

    
    // Condiciones
    $conditions = [];
    $params= [];

    if(!empty($data['nombre'])) {
      $conditions[] = 'C.nombre LIKE ?';
      $params[] = '%'.$data['nombre'].'%';
    }

    if(!empty($data['status'])) {
      $conditions[] = 'C.status = ?';
      $params[] = $data['status'];
    }

    // Si hay condiciones
    $where = '';
    if (!empty($conditions)) {
      $where = ' WHERE' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
    }

    // Orden
    // Arreglo asociativo donde:
    // - Las claves son los name de las columnas del DataTable JS
    // - Los valores son los nombre de las columnas de la Tabla SQL
    $orderColumns = [
      'Nombre' => 'nombre',
      'Estado' => 'status',
    ];
    $orders = [];
    if (is_array($data['order'])) {
        foreach($data['order'] as $info) {

            $columnName = $data['columns'][$info['column']]['name'];
            $dir = $info['dir'] == 'asc' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
            if (isset($orderColumns [$columnName])) {

               $orders[] = $orderColumns [$columnName] . ' ' . $dir;
            }
        }
    }
    // Si no se indico el orden, ponemos un orden por defecto
    if (empty($orders)) {
      $orders[] = "nombre ASC";
    }
    $order = "ORDER BY " . implode(', ', $orders);

    // Paginado
    $offset = (int) $data['start'];
    $length = (int) $data['length'];
    // Si no se indico la cantidad por pagina
    if ($length < 1) {
        $length = 10;
    }
    $limit = 'LIMIT ' . $length . ' OFFSET ' . $offset;

    try {
        // Obtenemos el total de registros en la tabla
        $stmt = $db->prepare(
          "SELECT COUNT(1) AS total
           FROM categorias AS C"
        );
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $all = $row['total'];

        // Obtenemos el total de registros que cumplen el $where
        $stmt = $db->prepare(
          "SELECT COUNT(1) AS total
           FROM categorias AS C
           $where"
        );
        $stmt->execute($params);
        $row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $total = $row['total'];

        // Obtenemos los registros correspondientes al paginado y ordenados
        $stmt = $db->prepare(
          "SELECT nombre, status
           FROM categorias AS C
           $where
           $order
           $limit"
        );
        $stmt->execute($params);
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $result = array(
            'data' => $rows, // registros de la pagina
            'recordsTotal' => $all, // total registros en la tabla
            'recordsFiltered' => $total, // total registros filtrados
            'draw' => $data['draw'], // Versión
        );
        echo json_encode($result);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
});
```

*NOTA: He tenido que crear la variable `$orderColumns` debido a que no has indicado para cada columna del `DataTable` el `data` (que es el campo sobre el cual se hace el mapeo directo). Así mismo como medida de seguridad, no deberías asumir que lo que viene en esa posición es un valor válido.*

---

Por último, dado que ahora `PHP` esta devolviendo mas información, es necesario actualizar los datos que le pasas al `callback` del `DataTable` (ver [Returned data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data)). Así por ejemplo:

```
...
ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {

  // Agregamos los filtros que actualmente estas enviando
  dataTablesParameters.nombre = this.categorias.nombre;
  dataTablesParameters.status = this.categorias.status;

  that.http
    .post(
      this.url + 'categorias/listar',
      dataTablesParameters
    ).subscribe(
      resp => {
        console.log(resp.data);
        callback(resp); // Aqui pasamos la respuesta
      },
      error => {
        console.log('fallo la conexion al servidor');
      }
    );
},
```

---

Referencias:

- [DataTables - Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)
- [PostgreSQL SELECT Syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html)

Comment: Solucione un pequeño error en **$limit = 'LIMIT ' . $length . ' OFFSET '.($start * $length);** (Esto porque yo uso PostgreSQL). El problema que hay es la paginacion que aun no la reconoce. [**Acá una captura**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzc9z.png).

Comment: La primera pág, genial, la segunda en adelante no. Capturas: [***Página 1***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3aFP.png), [***Página 2***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rojt7.png) y [***Página 3***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akp1W.png),

Comment: Genial, la paginacion esta resulta. Solo falta solucionar el ordenamiento. Capturas: [***Página 1***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKsjH.png), [***Página 2***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ov1h.png), [***Página 3***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvTqj.png) y [***Página 4***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f58w.png),

Comment: De hecho si lo había hecho, sucede que no le coloque las iniciales en mayúscula sino en minúsculas. Disculpa esa. Gracias por toda la ayuda.

Comment: @PabloContreras, he actualizado (y esta vez espero que sea la ultima) mi respuesta, agregando un comentario. Me alegra haber sido de ayuda, éxitos!

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres 10 resultados por página, tienes que usar la propiedad
pageLength e igualarla a 10

```
this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,

}
```

Y en el callback, vuelves a asignar el resultado de la respuesta resp.data a data, en vez de vaciar el array.

Puedes hacer esto:

```
personas: any (o el tipo que sea) = [];

constructor() blah blah //

this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  serverSide: true,
  filter: false,
  processing: true,
  autoWidth: true,
  searchable: false,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    that.http
      .post(
        this.url+'categorias/listar',
        {
          "nombre": this.categorias.nombre,
          "status": this.categorias.status,
        }
      ).subscribe(
        resp => {
          that.personas = resp.data;
          callback({
            recordsTotal: resp.data.length,
            recordsFiltered: resp.data.length,
            data: []
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log('fallo la conexion al servidor');
        }
      );
  },
  columns: [
// etc
```

Comment: Ya lo había intentado y tampoco lo soluciona.

Comment: Acabo de extender la respuesta.

Comment: Si lo guardo en "that.personas" como sugieres no me lo reconocerá la vista, puesto que no la formulo de la misma manera que en la guía, allí esta el código html que utilizo.